# Scraping using Beatiful Soup and Getting Error "Access to this page has been denied."

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am working on an Html parse and scraping Trulia with Beautiful soup in python. I am fairly new to python and feel as though my code is correct but I keep getting access denied. I assume this is because I am hitting the website too many times which is why I tried a sleep function, but even then I am getting access denied. I want to use a for loop to scrape multiple pages at once, I am still able to scrape one page at a time but whenever I attempt to scrape multiple and use the for loop I get access denied.

````
```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd 
import urllib.parse 

import time

real_estate_new=pd.DataFrame(columns=['Address', 'Beds', 'Baths', 'Price', 'sqft'])

address=[]
beds=[]
baths=[]
prices=[]
sqft=[]



for i in range(1,6):
time.sleep(5)
website = requests.get('https://www.trulia.com/for_sale/Knoxville,TN/1p_beds/' + str(i) + 
'_p/')
 #print('https://www.trulia.com/for_sale/Knoxville,TN/1p_beds/' + str(i) + '_p/')
 soup = BeautifulSoup(website.content, 'html.parser')

 
 result = soup.find_all('li', {'class' : 'Grid__CellBox-sc-144isrp-0 
 SearchResultsList__WideCell-b7y9ki-2 jiZmPM'})

 result_update = [k for k in result if k.has_attr('data-testid')]
 
 for result in result_update:
    
    try:
        address.append(result.find('div', {'data-testid':'property-address'}).get_text())
    except:
        address.append('n/a')
    print(address)
    try:
        beds.append(result.find('div', {'data-testid':'property-beds'}).get_text())
    except:
        beds.append('n/a')

    try:
        baths.append(result.find('div', {'data-testid':'property-baths'}).get_text())
    except:
        baths.append('n/a')    
    
    try:
        prices.append(result.find('div', {'data-testid':'property-price'}).get_text())
    except:
        prices.append('n/a')      
    
    try:
        sqft.append(result.find('div', {'data-testid':'property-price'}).get_text())
    except:
        sqft.append('n/a')      

for j in range (len(address)):
    real_estate_new=real_estate_new.append({'Address':address[j], 'Beds':beds[j], 
'Baths':baths[j], 'Price':prices[j], 'sqft':sqft[j]}, ignore_index=True)
print(soup.prettify())
````

Comment: Have you checked what is listed in `robots.txt`? It's likely that the host does not allow scraping. The file is normally at *http:/<domain>/robots.txt* I think there is an option in BS to ignore it but this won't always work.

Comment: Does the error happen immediately or can you still scrape a bit before it happens?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using graphql. First we need payload for query. Inside it, we can change pages, cities and everything we need to search. I will give an example of the first page with limits of 190. City of Knoxville, TN.

```
payload = json.dumps({
  "operationName": "WEB_searchResultsMapQuery",
  "variables": {
    "isSwipeableFactsEnabled": False,
    "heroImageFallbacks": [
      "STREET_VIEW",
      "SATELLITE_VIEW"
    ],
    "searchDetails": {
      "searchType": "FOR_SALE",
      "location": {
        "cities": [
          {
            "city": "Knoxville",
            "state": "TN"
          }
        ]
      },
      "filters": {
        "sort": {
          "type": "DATE",
          "ascending": False
        },
        "page": 1,
        "limit": 190,
        "isAlternateListingSource": False,
        "bedrooms": {
          "min": "1",
          "max": "*"
        },
        "propertyTypes": [],
        "listingTypes": [],
        "pets": [],
        "rentalListingTags": [],
        "foreclosureTypes": [],
        "buildingAmenities": [],
        "unitAmenities": [],
        "landlordPays": [],
        "offset": 40,
        "propertyAmenityTypes": []
      }
    },
    "includeOffMarket": False,
    "includeLocationPolygons": True,
    "isSPA": False,
    "includeNearBy": True
  },
  "query": "query WEB_searchResultsMapQuery($searchDetails: SEARCHDETAILS_Input!, $heroImageFallbacks: [MEDIA_HeroImageFallbackTypes!], $includeOffMarket: Boolean!, $includeLocationPolygons: Boolean!, $isSPA: Boolean!, $includeNearBy: Boolean!, $isSwipeableFactsEnabled: Boolean = false) {\n  searchResultMap: searchHomesByDetails(searchDetails: $searchDetails, includeNearBy: $includeNearBy) {\n    ...SearchResultsMapClientFragment\n    __typename\n  }\n  offMarketHomes: searchOffMarketHomes(searchDetails: $searchDetails) @include(if: $includeOffMarket) {\n    ...HomeMarkerLayersContainerFragment\n    ...HoverCardLayerFragment\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n\nfragment SearchResultsMapClientFragment on SEARCH_Result {\n  ...HomeMarkerLayersContainerFragment\n  ...HoverCardLayerFragment\n  ...SearchLocationBoundaryFragment @include(if: $includeLocationPolygons)\n  ...SchoolSearchMarkerLayerFragment\n  ...TransitLayerFragment\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment HomeMarkerLayersContainerFragment on SEARCH_Result {\n  ...HomeMarkersLayerFragment\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment HomeMarkersLayerFragment on SEARCH_Result {\n  homes {\n    location {\n      coordinates {\n        latitude\n        longitude\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    url\n    metadata {\n      compositeId\n      __typename\n    }\n    ...HomeMarkerFragment\n    __typename\n  }\n  nearByHomes {\n    ...HomeMarkerFragment\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment HomeMarkerFragment on HOME_Details {\n  media {\n    hasThreeDHome\n    __typename\n  }\n  location {\n    coordinates {\n      latitude\n      longitude\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n  displayFlags {\n    enableMapPin\n    __typename\n  }\n  price {\n    calloutMarkerPrice: formattedPrice(formatType: SHORT_ABBREVIATION)\n    __typename\n  }\n  url\n  ... on HOME_Property {\n    activeForSaleListing {\n      openHouses {\n        formattedDay\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n  ...HomeDetailsTopThirdFragment @include(if: $isSPA)\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment HomeDetailsTopThirdFragment on HOME_Details {\n  bathrooms {\n    summaryBathrooms: formattedValue(formatType: COMMON_ABBREVIATION)\n    __typename\n  }\n  bedrooms {\n    summaryBedrooms: formattedValue(formatType: COMMON_ABBREVIATION)\n    __typename\n  }\n  floorSpace {\n    formattedDimension\n    __typename\n  }\n  location {\n    city\n    coordinates {\n      latitude\n      longitude\n      __typename\n    }\n    neighborhoodName\n    stateCode\n    zipCode\n    cityStateZipAddress: formattedLocation(formatType: CITY_STATE_ZIP)\n    homeFormattedAddress: formattedLocation\n    summaryFormattedLocation: formattedLocation(formatType: STREET_COMMUNITY_BUILDER)\n    __typename\n  }\n  media {\n    metaTagHeroImages: heroImage(fallbacks: $heroImageFallbacks) {\n      url {\n        desktop: custom(size: {width: 2048, height: 200})\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    topThirdHeroImages: heroImage(fallbacks: $heroImageFallbacks) {\n      __typename\n      url {\n        extraSmallSrc: custom(size: {width: 375, height: 275})\n        smallSrc: custom(size: {width: 570, height: 275})\n        mediumSrc: custom(size: {width: 768, height: 500})\n        largeSrc: custom(size: {width: 992, height: 500})\n        hiDipExtraSmallSrc: custom(size: {width: 1125, height: 825})\n        hiDpiSmallSrc: custom(size: {width: 1710, height: 825})\n        hiDpiMediumSrc: custom(size: {width: 2048, height: 1536})\n        __typename\n      }\n      webpUrl: url(compression: webp) {\n        extraSmallWebpSrc: custom(size: {width: 375, height: 275})\n        smallWebpSrc: custom(size: {width: 570, height: 275})\n        mediumWebpSrc: custom(size: {width: 768, height: 500})\n        largeWebpSrc: custom(size: {width: 992, height: 500})\n        hiDipExtraSmallWebpSrc: custom(size: {width: 1125, height: 825})\n        hiDpiSmallWebpSrc: custom(size: {width: 1710, height: 825})\n        hiDpiMediumWebpSrc: custom(size: {width: 2048, height: 1536})\n        __typename\n      }\n    }\n    totalPhotoCount\n    __typename\n  }\n  metadata {\n    compositeId\n    currentListingId\n    __typename\n  }\n  pageText {\n    title\n    metaDescription\n    __typename\n  }\n  price {\n    formattedPrice\n    ... on HOME_LastSoldPrice {\n      formattedPriceDifferencePercent\n      formattedSoldDate(dateFormat: \"MMM D, YYYY\")\n      listingPrice {\n        formattedPrice(formatType: SHORT_ABBREVIATION)\n        __typename\n      }\n      priceDifferencePercent\n      pricePerDimension {\n        formattedDimension\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    ... on HOME_ForeclosureEstimatePrice {\n      price\n      typeDescription\n      __typename\n    }\n    ... on HOME_PriceRange {\n      currencyCode\n      max\n      min\n      __typename\n    }\n    ... on HOME_SinglePrice {\n      currencyCode\n      price\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n  tracking {\n    key\n    value\n    __typename\n  }\n  url\n  ... on HOME_Property {\n    currentStatus {\n      isOffMarket\n      isRecentlySold\n      isForeclosure\n      isActiveForRent\n      isActiveForSale\n      isRecentlyRented\n      label\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n  ... on HOME_RentalCommunity {\n    location {\n      rentalCommunityFormattedLocation: formattedLocation(formatType: STREET_COMMUNITY_NAME)\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment HoverCardLayerFragment on SEARCH_Result {\n  homes {\n    ...HomeHoverCardFragment\n    __typename\n  }\n  nearByHomes {\n    ...HomeHoverCardFragment\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment HomeHoverCardFragment on HOME_Details {\n  ...HomeDetailsCardFragment\n  ...HomeDetailsCardHeroFragment\n  ...HomeDetailsCardPhotosFragment\n  ...HomeDetailsGroupInsightsFragment @include(if: $isSwipeableFactsEnabled)\n  location {\n    coordinates {\n      latitude\n      longitude\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n  displayFlags {\n    enableMapPin\n    showMLSLogoOnMapMarkerCard\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment HomeDetailsCardFragment on HOME_Details {\n  __typename\n  location {\n    city\n    stateCode\n    zipCode\n    fullLocation: formattedLocation(formatType: STREET_CITY_STATE_ZIP)\n    partialLocation: formattedLocation(formatType: STREET_ONLY)\n    __typename\n  }\n  price {\n    formattedPrice\n    __typename\n  }\n  url\n  tags(include: MINIMAL) {\n    level\n    formattedName\n    icon {\n      vectorImage {\n        svg\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n  fullTags: tags {\n    level\n    formattedName\n    icon {\n      vectorImage {\n        svg\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n  floorSpace {\n    formattedDimension\n    __typename\n  }\n  lotSize {\n    ... on HOME_SingleDimension {\n      formattedDimension(minDecimalDigits: 2, maxDecimalDigits: 2)\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n  bedrooms {\n    formattedValue(formatType: TWO_LETTER_ABBREVIATION)\n    __typename\n  }\n  bathrooms {\n    formattedValue(formatType: TWO_LETTER_ABBREVIATION)\n    __typename\n  }\n  isSaveable\n  preferences {\n    isSaved\n    __typename\n  }\n  metadata {\n    compositeId\n    legacyIdForSave\n    __typename\n  }\n  tracking {\n    key\n    value\n    __typename\n  }\n  displayFlags {\n    showMLSLogoOnListingCard\n    addAttributionProminenceOnListCard\n    __typename\n  }\n  ... on HOME_RoomForRent {\n    numberOfRoommates\n    availableDate: formattedAvailableDate(dateFormat: \"MMM D\")\n    providerListingId\n    __typename\n  }\n  ... on HOME_RentalCommunity {\n    activeListing {\n      provider {\n        summary(formatType: SHORT)\n        listingSource {\n          logoUrl\n          __typename\n        }\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    location {\n      communityLocation: formattedLocation(formatType: STREET_COMMUNITY_NAME)\n      __typename\n    }\n    providerListingId\n    __typename\n  }\n  ... on HOME_Property {\n    currentStatus {\n      isRecentlySold\n      isRecentlyRented\n      isActiveForRent\n      isActiveForSale\n      isOffMarket\n      isForeclosure\n      __typename\n    }\n    priceChange {\n      priceChangeDirection\n      __typename\n    }\n    activeListing {\n      provider {\n        summary(formatType: SHORT)\n        extraShortSummary: summary(formatType: EXTRA_SHORT)\n        listingSource {\n          logoUrl\n          __typename\n        }\n        __typename\n      }\n      dateListed\n      __typename\n    }\n    lastSold {\n      provider {\n        summary(formatType: SHORT)\n        extraShortSummary: summary(formatType: EXTRA_SHORT)\n        listingSource {\n          logoUrl\n          __typename\n        }\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    providerListingId\n    __typename\n  }\n  ... on HOME_FloorPlan {\n    priceChange {\n      priceChangeDirection\n      __typename\n    }\n    provider {\n      summary(formatType: SHORT)\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n\nfragment HomeDetailsCardHeroFragment on HOME_Details {\n  media {\n    heroImage(fallbacks: $heroImageFallbacks) {\n      url {\n        small\n        __typename\n      }\n      webpUrl: url(compression: webp) {\n        small\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment HomeDetailsCardPhotosFragment on HOME_Details {\n  media {\n    __typename\n    heroImage(fallbacks: $heroImageFallbacks) {\n      url {\n        small\n        __typename\n      }\n      webpUrl: url(compression: webp) {\n        small\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    photos {\n      url {\n        small\n        __typename\n      }\n      webpUrl: url(compression: webp) {\n        small\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment HomeDetailsGroupInsightsFragment on HOME_Details {\n  ... on HOME_Property {\n    groupedInsights {\n      insights {\n        ... on HOME_FeatureInsights {\n          insightTags {\n            formattedName\n            __typename\n          }\n          __typename\n        }\n        ... on HOME_SmartInsights {\n          insightTags {\n            formattedName\n            __typename\n          }\n          __typename\n        }\n        ... on HOME_ContextualPhrases {\n          phrases {\n            description\n            __typename\n          }\n          __typename\n        }\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment SearchLocationBoundaryFragment on SEARCH_Result {\n  location {\n    encodedPolygon\n    ... on SEARCH_ResultLocationCity {\n      locationId\n      __typename\n    }\n    ... on SEARCH_ResultLocationCounty {\n      locationId\n      __typename\n    }\n    ... on SEARCH_ResultLocationNeighborhood {\n      locationId\n      __typename\n    }\n    ... on SEARCH_ResultLocationPostalCode {\n      locationId\n      __typename\n    }\n    ... on SEARCH_ResultLocationState {\n      locationId\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment SchoolSearchMarkerLayerFragment on SEARCH_Result {\n  schools {\n    ...SchoolMarkersLayerFragment\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment SchoolMarkersLayerFragment on School {\n  id\n  latitude\n  longitude\n  categories\n  ...SchoolHoverCardFragment\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment SchoolHoverCardFragment on School {\n  id\n  name\n  gradesRange\n  providerRating {\n    rating\n    __typename\n  }\n  streetAddress\n  studentCount\n  latitude\n  longitude\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment TransitLayerFragment on SEARCH_Result {\n  transitStations {\n    stationName\n    iconUrl\n    coordinates {\n      latitude\n      longitude\n      __typename\n    }\n    radius\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n"
})
```

Now we need set up headers:

```
headers = {
  'authority': 'www.trulia.com',
  'accept': '*/*',
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.127 Safari/537.36',
}
```

POST request to provide us with a huge amount of information. I will display what you had in the example.

```
url = "https://www.trulia.com/graphql"

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
results = []
for home in json.loads(response.text)['data']['searchResultMap']['homes']:
    results.append([home['location']['fullLocation'], home['bedrooms']['formattedValue'],
          home['bathrooms']['formattedValue'], home['price']['formattedPrice'],
          home['floorSpace']['formattedDimension']])

real_estate_new = pd.DataFrame(data=results, columns=['Address', 'Beds', 'Baths', 'Price', 'sqft'])
print(real_estate_new)
```

Outputs:

```
                                          Address Beds  ...       Price        sqft
0          8121 Corteland Dr, Knoxville, TN 37909  3bd  ...    $450,000  2,340 sqft
1           525 Brunello Way, Knoxville, TN 37919  4bd  ...    $749,900  2,864 sqft
2           529 Brunello Way, Knoxville, TN 37919  4bd  ...    $749,900  2,864 sqft
3     1211 Highland Ave #204, Knoxville, TN 37916  1bd  ...    $150,000    598 sqft
4           6836 Old Kent Dr, Knoxville, TN 37919  4bd  ...  $1,299,900  3,308 sqft
..                                            ...  ...  ...         ...         ...
185           Sevier Meadows, Knoxville, TN 37920  4bd  ...   $330,990+  2,804 sqft
186  1900 Ridgecrest Dr #201, Knoxville, TN 37918  2bd  ...    $299,900  1,747 sqft
187       9919 Dayflower Way, Knoxville, TN 37932  3bd  ...    $400,000  2,688 sqft
188              Coward Mill, Knoxville, TN 37919  4bd  ...   $321,990+  1,764 sqft
189    315 Justice Valley St, Knoxville, TN 37934  4bd  ...    $999,900  3,123 sqft
```

Comment: You can also use `json=payload` (and just pass the dictionary). On the return just use `response.json()[....`  No need then to directly `import json`

Comment: How would I use this code to extract more data, when I try and expand the limits I eventually get an error right at 300, is there a way for me to get multiple pages? I know there are many more homes for sale in the Knoxville area and was curious how I could potentially get all of them, I belive there is over 600 when you search knoxville. By get more I mean within the same data frame rather than 2 or more seperate dataframes.

Comment: u can do it like function in a loop, and change page in payload